# Obtener la key correspondiente al valor mínimo dentro de un diccionario

Tags: python

Si tengo un diccionario `Python`. ¿cómo obtengo la `key` de la entrada que contiene el valor mínimo?

Estaba pensando en algo relacionado con la función [min()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#min).

Dada la información:

```
{320:1, 321:0, 322:3}
```

Devolvería `321`.

Referencia: [Get the key corresponding to the minimum value within a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282823/get-the-key-corresponding-to-the-minimum-value-within-a-dictionary)

Comment: Deberias señalar explicitamente el crédito, quizas asi no recibirias los downvotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo mejor se puede hacer es utilizar:

```
min(d, key=d.get)
```

Por ninguna razón debes interponer una inútil capa indirecta `lambda` o extraer `items()` o `keys()`.

## Metodo `min()`

El método `min()` devuelve el elemento más pequeño en un iterable o más pequeño de dos o más parámetros.

## Parametros`min()`

`min()` tiene dos tipos de argumentos con los que puede trabajar.

- `min(iterable, *iterables[, key, default])`

  - `iterable` - secuencia (tuple, string), colección (set, dictionary) o un objeto iterador cuyo elemento más pequeño se encuentre.
  - `*iterables (Opcional)` - cualquier número de iterables cuyo más pequeño se encuentre.
  - `key (Opcional)` - función donde se pasan los iterables y se realiza una comparación basada en su valor de retorno.
  - `default (Opcional)` - valor default si el iterable dado está vacío.
- `min(arg1, arg2, *args[, key])`

  - `arg1` - primer objeto obligatorio para la comparación (puede ser un número, un string u otro objeto).
  - `arg2` - segundo objeto obligatorio para la comparación (puede ser un número, un string u otro objeto).
  - `*args (Opcional)` - otros objetos de comparación.
  - `key` - donde se pasa cada argumento y la comparación se realiza en base a su valor de retorno.